# Why does my directive (restrict: 'C') not get put in when using interpolated value in class attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a few directives that are all triggered by the class attribute (`restrict: 'C'`). I want the directive that is triggered to be dynamic, and so I tried using `{{}}` within the class attribute. However, this doesn't trigger the directive as expected. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ScGKy/

When I try to use the directive without any interpolation on the class, it works fine. However, as soon as I try to use the `{{}}` within the class, it no longer works. As can be seen by the CSS, it is setting the class name correctly, but it's not triggering the directive. Is there a reason I can't use class directives like this?

Comment: Compilation occurs *before* interpolation so there's no way to specify a dynamic directive like this. A better approach would be to use a directive that compiles your dynamic directive on-the-fly.